# org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session for hibernate + JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm trying to query database from a tomcat listener via hibernate session before tomcat container starts. Here I'm getting the org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session error. Also When trying to attach the object with hibernate session it's giving error

My Setup:
1. have a tomcat listener where the same implements ServletContextListener 
2. start spring applicationcontext via this listener
3. configured hibernate with JPA within spring

listener : in this listener I'm trying to load my spring applicationContext and call my DAO via hibernate session to get DB data. Also I'm starting one thread pool to allocate the task depends on the DB query

```
@Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {

    ServletContext servletContext = sce.getServletContext();

        logger.debug("initializing the servletContextListener for AlarmThreadPool...");

        try {

            String springFileName = sce.getServletContext().getInitParameter("CONFIG_SPRING_FILE");
            ApplicationContextContainer.getInstance(springFileName, sce.getServletContext());

            IAriCloudDAO ariCloudDAO = (IAriCloudDAO) ApplicationContextContainer.getBean("ariCloudDAO");
            logger.debug("got the dao bean...");
            if (null != ariCloudDAO) {
                System.out.println("got the instace of DAO");
                int metricID = 1;
                List<CloudAlarmConfig> cloudAlarmConfigs = ariCloudDAO.getAllUsageAlarm(metricID);
                logger.info("the DAO entry got as " +cloudAlarmConfigs);
            }

            ThreadFactory threadFactory = new ThreadFactoryBuilder()
                    .setNameFormat("alarm-thread-%d")
                    //.setDaemon(true)
                    .build();

            ScheduledExecutorService exec = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2, threadFactory);
            servletContext.setAttribute("alarmThreadPool", exec);

        }catch (Exception e) {
            logger.fatal("ERROR::", e);
        }                   
    }
```

DAO IMPL:

```
@Override
@Transactional
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<CloudAlarmConfig> getAllUsageAlarm(int metricID) {

    Session session = mySessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    Query q = session
            .createQuery("SELECT e FROM CloudAlarmConfig e WHERE METRIC=:METRIC");
    q.setParameter("METRIC", metricID);
    logger.debug("query string got as :"+ q.getQueryString());
    List<CloudAlarmConfig> cloudAlarmConfigs = q.list();

    if (!cloudAlarmConfigs.isEmpty()) {
        return cloudAlarmConfigs;
    } else {
        return new ArrayList<CloudAlarmConfig>();
    }
}
```

JPA entity:

I'm using LazyInitialization for entity joining.

```
@JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    private UserEntity userEntity;
```

Getting the below exception when trying to execute the DAO call.

> org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy
>   - no Session  at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:164)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:285)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:185)
>     at
>   com.aricent.aricloud.entity.UserEntity_$$_javassist_6.toString(UserEntity_$$_javassist_6.java)
>     at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2902)   at
>   java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:128)    at
>   com.aricent.aricloud.entity.CloudAlarmConfig.toString(CloudAlarmConfig.java:234)
>     at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2902)   at
>   java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:128)

As I understood from several post that the hibernate session lives for one request and then it closed, the entity has been detached from session. But when trying to reattach the same with below code in DAO impl it gives me different error

```
Session session = mySessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
session.update(CloudAlarmConfig.class);
```

> org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: java.lang.Class   at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1141)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:1433)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:233)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultUpdateEventListener.java:55)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireUpdate(SessionImpl.java:786)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.update(SessionImpl.java:778)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.update(SessionImpl.java:774)
>     at
>   com.aricent.aricloud.dao.AricloudDAOImpl.getAllUsageAlarm(AricloudDAOImpl.java:959)

How can I overcome this. Please suggest.

Comment: In this line ´session.update(CloudAlarmConfig.class);` you have to set an instance of the class as parameter not the class it self.

Comment: Did u add `hibernate.current_session_context_class` property to a Thread and implement somethin like contextListener wich wud open the `Session` so that you can access that session anywhere else by using d `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()`. 

You should never use "1 session per web app", session is not a thread safe object - cannot be shared by multiple threads. You'd always use "1 session per request" or "1 session per transaction".

I cannot see `sessionFactory.openSession()` anywere in the code. Make sure u open the 'Session'. May be thats y u are getting **no Session** exception

Comment: `<property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>`

Comment: @LalitRao - I guess I should not set the property <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property> as I'm using spring managed transactions

Comment: Wats d big deal in **trying** once. You never know if it might work.

Comment: ya I tried that before, gave exception like --org.hibernate.HibernateException: contains is not valid without active transaction

Comment: Can you Please accept the answer if it has helped you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overriding the `toString()` method of `CloudAlarmConfig` class and trying to access the lazily loaded instances of `UserEntity`.

So in your code -

```
List<CloudAlarmConfig> cloudAlarmConfigs = ariCloudDAO.getAllUsageAlarm(metricID);
logger.info("the DAO entry got as " +cloudAlarmConfigs);
```

This makes call to toString method which internally tries to access the "UserEntity", so when you are trying to access the entity outside the Hibernate session, you are getting Lazy exception as `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session at`.

To fix this issue, you have to load the instances of `UserEntity` when the session is still open.

Coming to second exception which is `org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: java.lang.Class at`, Jens has provided explanation in his comments. The code should be like this:

```
Session session = mySessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
session.update(cloudAlarmConfig);
```

Here `cloudAlarmConfig` represents the instance of `CloudAlarmConfig class`.

**Update:**

To update a record, first you should have a valid object with proper id in it. So you can try like this:

```
 Session session = mySessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
 CloudAlarmConfig cloudAlarmConfig = (CloudAlarmConfig) session.get(CloudAlarmConfig.class,100); // Assuming 100 is one of the primary key in Databse table for CloudAlarmConfig entity.     

// Do some modifications to this object, then call the update operation.
session.update(cloudAlarmConfig);
```

Comment: after removing the UserEntity from toString the Lazy loading is working... I will try to load the UserEntity and pass it to toString() . Thanks a lot

Comment: ragarding the secong exception - if I do session.update(new CloudAlarmConfig()); doesn't it try to update the table ? it's giving me error like `org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value: com.aricent.aricloud.entity.CloudAlarmConfig.alarmName` where alarmName is a column in my table. I just want to query the DB. Please let me know

Comment: @bagui, now your question is just a basic Java question. When you create a new Object and ask hibernate to update the record in database then what you are expecting hibernate to do? Hibernate will not know which record in database your object is representing. See my updated answer to get an idea on how you can do that.